# Update Post_Content for Empty in All Posts from Category - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to delete all "post_content" content of Wordpress posts with the specific category.

```
UPDATE wpp_posts join wp_term_relationships on (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
where wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 410
SET post_content =

''
```

is generating error.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where wpp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 410

SET post_content =

''' at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET post_content=''` must be before where clause.

```
UPDATE wpp_posts join wp_term_relationships on (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
SET post_content = '' 
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 410
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!